# How can I highlight specific bars by category in ggplot 2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Using `ggplot2`, I'm trying to color a specific set of bars using 2 different colors, according to their categories. In the plot below, I have columns over a certain value filled in red, but due to my method it excludes their 'partner columns' (the cols on top of them) from the coloring, when I would like them to be filled with blue.

If I change the values in `scale_fill_manual()` then it doesn't do anything as the 'fill' expression will give priority to coloring the 'TRUE' and 'FALSE' categories.

How can I change my code so that the bars accompanying the filled red bars will be colored blue?

My current plot:

[image]

My code:

```
pop %>%  
  group_by(age_range, sex) %>% 
  summarize(population = sum(population)) %>% 
  mutate(prop = population / sum(population)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col(aes(x = age_range, y = prop, color = sex, 
               fill = (prop >= .504 & sex == 'female' & age_range != '75 - 79'), 
               width = .85), 
           position = 'dodge') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('Grey60', 'Grey60', 'Blue', 'Red')) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('Red', 'Blue')) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = age_range, y = prop, fill = sex, label = percent(prop)),
            position = position_dodge(width = .9), 
            vjust = .358, hjust = 1.1,size = 4, color = 'White') +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = .504, color = 'Grey', alpha = .7) + 
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
# define TRUE / FALSE condition, then assign the same condition
# to the male group within the same age range
pop <- pop %>%
  mutate(condition = prop >= 0.504 & sex == "female" & age_range != '75 - 79') %>%
  group_by(age_range) %>%
  mutate(condition = any(condition))

# define colour / fill scale for gender
sex.scale <- c("female" = "red", "male" = "blue")

ggplot(pop,
       aes(x = age_range, y = prop, 
           color = sex, group = sex, 
           label = scales::percent(prop))) +

  # bars with colored outlines & grey fill
  geom_col(position = "dodge", fill = "grey60") +

  # bars with coloured fill; only visible if condition is TRUE
  geom_col(aes(fill = sex, alpha = condition),
           position = "dodge") +

  scale_color_manual(values = sex.scale) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = sex.scale, guide = F) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1, "FALSE" = 0)) +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),
            vjust = .358, hjust = 1.1,
            size = 4,
            color = 'White') +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = .504, color = 'Grey', alpha = .7) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image: plot]

sample subset data:

```
pop <- data.frame(
  age_range = rep(c("10-14", "15-19", "20-24", "25-29"), each = 2),
  sex = rep(c("male", "female"), by = 4),
  prop = c(0.51, 0.49, 0.518, 0.482, 0.495, 0.505, 0.446, 0.554)
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! Your answer is exactly what I needed!